# Cmake complains there is no source code when building MySQL

Tags: mysql, cmake

I'm trying to build MySQL from source code.
But when I try to run cmake using commnad following `cmake ..` I get the error following.
Since I'm first to use cmake, I don't know what is happend. Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks.

```
CMake Error at cmake/libutils.cmake:103 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Cannot find source file:

    get_password.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  libmysql/CMakeLists.txt:217 (ADD_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are trying to build? E.g. in MySQL 5.5 the file `get_password.c` is actually listed in [libmysql/CMakeLists.txt:140](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.5/libmysql/CMakeLists.txt#L140), but the file definitely exists under `libmysql` subdirectory.

Comment: I try to build the version 5.7.13. As you mentioned, there is ```get_password.c``` at under ```client``` subdirectory. However, Cmake complains that there is not ```get_password.c```. Since I'm the first to ```cmake``` I don't know how to solve. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: "As you mentioned, there is `get_password.c` at under `client` subdirectory." - Eh? You need to search the file under `libmysql` directory, not under `client` one. Because the error is emitted during the processing of `CMakeLists.txt` under `libmysql` directory (see the error message), `add_library` will search source files under that directory, not under `client` one. According to the [repository](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-5.7.13/libmysql/get_password.c), the file `get_password.c` actually exists under `libmysql`, so the error shouldn't occur.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It seems that my source tree is quite wired.